# Dispatching events from webkit for consumption in Adobe AIR

Tags: webkit, air

I have a webkit HTML component in my AIR application, and would like to be able to respond to events such as onclick and ondoubleclick generated from the HTML in the webkit component. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, although it took me a little while to find it.

This should serve as a pretty good starting off point: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ProgrammingHTMLAndJavaScript_04.html

Here's the key code:

```
var html:HTMLLoader = new HTMLLoader();
var foo:String = "Hello from container SWF." 
function helloFromJS(message:String):void {
    trace("JavaScript says:", message);
}
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("test.html");
html.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
html.load(urlReq);

function loaded(e:Event):void{
    html.window.foo = foo;
    html.window.helloFromJS = helloFromJS;
}
```

The HTML content (in a file named test.html) loaded into the HTMLLoader object in the previous example can access the foo property and the helloFromJS() method defined in the parent SWF file:

```
<html>
    <script>
        function alertFoo() {
            alert(foo); 
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <button onClick="alertFoo()">
            What is foo?
        </button>
        <p><button onClick="helloFromJS('Hi.')">
            Call helloFromJS() function.
        </button></p>
    </body>
</html>
```